# Angularfire get data of a nested collection or shema dseign on firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing an application to save attendance of a company. Here is the achema:

```
--attendance(collection)
      --Year(document)
            --month(collection)
                  --day(document)
                        --present(collection)
                              --employee record
                              --employee record
```

Here is the angularfire query i made:

```
db.collection("attendance").doc("2023").collection("3").doc("21").collection("present").get().subscribe(ss=>{
      console.log(ss.size);//Giving 0 but collection has 4 records
})
```

Angularfire library version:

```
"@angular/fire": "^7.5.0"
```

I am getting 0 records when i made the above query. Suggest me a way to get data from the present eollection or a good schema design for this attendance.

Comment: Do you get any error? Are they security rules that could prevent reading the data? Is your collection named `attendance` or `Attendance`, see the difference of case of the first letter in your question. Which version of the JS SDK are you using? FYI I’ve voted to close your question because all of these missing information.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec i have updated my question. Please havea look now. I get no error but get 0 size on console.

Comment: If the `console.log(ss.size);` runs, the database got a result and it contained `0` documents. You might want to check the path to the collection for non-printable characters (like extra spaces at the end). If that doesn't solve it, add a screenshot to your question of a document that you expect to get back from this read operation showing the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really versed in AngularFire but the documentation shows that version 7.5.0 is compatible with Firebase version 9 and not with Firebase version 8.

You use Firebase syntax V8 and you should adapt your code to V9, see the Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_7) as well as the Angular Fire [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/HEAD/docs/version-7-upgrade.md).